# Why Python IDE shows such error even when it is installed correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

1. it show such as turtle.Terminator
2. AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward'

```
>>> import turtle
>>> for i in range(50,100,10):
...     for j in range(4):
...             turtle.forward(i)
...             turtle.left(90)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in forward
turtle.Terminator
```

Note: my excepted result is 4 square

Comment: This code runs fine for me in Jupyter notebook

Comment: You say that there is an AttributeError, but your snippet does not show it. Please can you show us where you got an AttributeError. Also, are you running code on an online interpreter such as repl.it or trinket.io or are you using a local copy of idle?

Comment: >>> import turtle
>>> turtle.title('Turtle Graphics')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    turtle.title('Turtle Graphics')
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'title'
>>>